# Sorting an array alphabetically

Tags: java

I have an array which i need to sort its elements by occurrence then alphabetically.
For example:

```
55 The
32 ASomething
32 BSomething

ASomething should come before Bsomething because:
1) they have the same number
2) A comes before B alphabetically
```

So you sort first by the number of occurrence then Alphabetically

What is the best way to do that.
I am using merge sort to sort the counts but how do I put a statement that it will check if they have the same number, it sorts alphabetically (could be more than 2 words).

SOLUTION: What I did is a merge sort on the data before I did a merge sorts on the counts of data and that was good enough :) Thanks everyone for the help

Comment: Not that this affects how you deal with the counts, but is your sort case-sensitive or case-insensitive?

Comment: My first thought was, wow, this would be really easy in the bash shell.  :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that you are using Java.  That's why the smiley.  I can do it in Java, but it takes a lot more than the 1 line of piped bash commands.  :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a custom [`Comparator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for that using [`Arrays.sort()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)):

```
Arrays.sort(array, new CustomComparator());

public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {
  private final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s+(.*)");

  public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    Matcher m1 = pattern.matcher(s1);
    if (!m1.matches()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("s1 doesn't match: " + s1);
    }
    Matcher m2 = pattern.matcher(s2);
    if (!m2.matches()) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("s2 doesn't match: " + s2);
    }
    int i1 = Integer.parseInt(m1.group(1));
    int i2 = Integer.parseInt(m2.group(1));
    if (i1 < i2) {
      return 1;
    } else if (i1 > i2) {
      return -1;
    }
    return m1.group(2).compareTo(m2.group(2));
  }
}
```

For [`Collections`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) you can use [`Collections.sort()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

The above assumes your array elements are `String`s like `"22 ASomething"` rather than a specific data structure containing occurrences and some text. If that is the case you can use a simpler `Comparator`.

Also if you do have an array of `String`s it might be worth first transforming it into an array of objects that have been parsed to save over-parsing the elements (ie some elements will be parsed more than once).

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that the sorting algorithm you are using guarantees "stability" as does [java.util.Collections.sort](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)):

> This sort is guaranteed to be stable: equal elements will not be reordered as a result of the sort.

You make no mention of what data structure you are using which would definitely guide your approach. For example, you might use a Map> to model your data in which case it would make sense to sort the Lists and then iterate through the ordered keys of the Map. This would not require a custom Comparator.

Comment: Why do you think OP needs a *stable* sort?

Comment: Because the OP had a two pass sort "So you sort first by the number of occurrence then Alphabetically"