# sort arrays of array in lexiographical order

Tags: java, arrays

I was wondering how can I sort arrays of array. For example, I have got a char array like

```
0[a,b]
1[b,a]
2[a,a]
```

and this should be sorted to:

```
0[a,a]
1[a,b]
2[b,a]
```

In other words I want to sort the different array locations in lexicographical order.

Comment: Write a class that implements `Comparator` and use the API methods with it... What have you tried?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376134/sorting-an-array-alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

You can define an implementation of a [`Comparator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for that, where `T` is an array of the type that you wish to sort lexicographically:

```
String[][] a = ...
Arrays.sort(a, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    compare(String[] lhs, String[] rhs) {
        // Compare lhs to rhs, and return a result that indicates
        // which one comes earlier lexicographically
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is just char arrays then I would just search the arrays for the first letter and sort them, by that. and if any match then to sort them by the next letter, and so on.

Easiest way would be to do it recursively, or atleast in loops.

Comment: Using `Comparator`s would be much easier than this.

Comment: People who ask these questions are usually in a coding class. And you have to learn how the Comparator works before you should just use it. Like how no one ever learns about arraylists, they learn about Arrays.

Comment: I would say that learning how a `Comparator` works is easier than writing sorting algorithms by hand. Additionally, new coders should learn the correct way from day one.

Comment: you never learn to code that way, because you never learn completely how the system works. And I would bet you didnt learn to code that way.